# XlsxWriter and Python inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, super, xlsxwriter

I just started working with XlsxWriter and I wanted to write my own methods to simplify writing excels, as the data I have has always the same format more or less.

I wanted to do this completely transparent writing a module that inherits `XlsxWriter` and that for who doesn't need my methods using my module it's the same that using directly `XlsxWriter`, while if at a certain point one of my methods is needed it can be used, without any change in code or adding more objects working in the same file/object.

So I started writing a module:

```
import xlsxwriter

class XlsxMaster(xlsxwriter.Workbook):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(XlsxMaster, self).__init__(filename)

    def write_results(self):
        print "write results"
```

Then I can use:

```
from xlsx_Master import XlsxMaster

workbook = XlsxMaster('./Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheet.write_results()
```

The problem is that this doesn't work as the worksheet object is derived from `xlsxwriter.worksheet` and not from my module, it can be called correctly through `workbook.write_results()` but this isn't what I want.
How can I add methods to `xlsxwriter.worksheet` in this way?
I don't know how to solve this elegantly. Maybe there's a way or maybe I took the wrong way from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

I took a slightly different approach and it was working well enough to produce xls output in a web app.

Rather than overriding the xlswriter stuff, I just developed a Facade object that was matched what I was trying to do and then would just call on the underlying xlswriter assets to do the work.

```
import xlsxwriter

class ExcelWriter(object):

    def getColFormatInfo(self, fieldname):
        #some app-specific stuff...
        f = FieldFormat.factory(self.rdb, fieldname)
        # width = 30
        label = f.SHORTNAME
        width = max(f.LENGTH, len(label)) 
        return width, label

    def __init__(self, rdb, title):
        self.rdb = rdb
        self.fnp = "/tmp/%s.xlsx" % (title)
        wb = self.workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(self.fnp)

        #http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/format.html#set_bg_color
        self.fmt_title = wb.add_format(dict(bold=True))
        self.fmt_title.set_bg_color("#F5F5F5")
        self.fmt_title.set_border(1)

        self.fmt_colheader = wb.add_format(dict(bold=True))
        self.fmt_colheader.set_bottom(2)


        self.fmt_link = wb.add_format({'color': 'blue', 'underline': 1})

    def add_worksheet(self, wsname):
        return self.workbook.add_worksheet(wsname)

    def write_title(self, ws, row, col, s):
        ws.write(row, col, s, self.fmt_title)

    def write_colheader(self, ws, row, col, s):
        ws.write(row, col, s, self.fmt_colheader)

    def write(self, ws, row, col, s):
        ws.write(row, col, s)

    def write_url(self, ws, row, col, url, s):
        ws.write_url(row, col, url, self.fmt_link, s)
```

As you can see, what I was doing is to pre-compute some xls formats and make use of them in things like **write_colheader**.

But you could generalize that approach to create more user-friendly simple functions to carry out complex xlswriter actions behind the scenes.

I can't find the code that I was using to interact with it but it worked well enough.  The only thing is that it was a lot of manual **put xyz at 1,13** type of code that I was writing.  The normal, html, side of my web app was using **django-tables2** to generate html and it was a lot less code.

So my plan is to go back and rewrite the reporting to be more declarative-based, with a reporting front-end that would then take care of all the nitty-gritty commands to pass on to ExcelWriter - I still expect ExcelWriter to have roughly the same kind of API however.

Oh, and aside from the declarative-based changes, one thing I would immediately change in a new implementation would be to store formatting constants like the background color #F5F5F5 in a Json file and pass that in to the ExcelWriter at initialization:

Something like:

```
self.fmt_title.set_bg_color(
    self.j_config.get("fmt_title",{}).get("bg_color", "F5F5F5")
    )
```

In regard to the OPs comment about having to pass in variables, here are some updated function defs as a possible workaround.

```
def add_worksheet(self, wsname):
    ws = self.current_ws = self.workbook.add_worksheet(wsname)
    return ws

#you'd also need to have a set_current_ws function

def write_url(self, row, col, url, s, ws=None, fmt=None):
    ws = ws or self.current_ws
    fmt = fmt or self.fmt_link

    ws.write_url(row, col, url, fmt, s)
```

Comment: That's for sure another succesful way to implement it, but goes a little far from what I wanted. As for every method I have to pass the worksheet to work on. Nothing drammatic for me but as someonelse will use my script even if simple he will see it "something more". I will consider this idea even if at the moment I still prefer @pacholik one even if more complex to implement.

Comment: Noted.  I added some possible changes.  At the end of the day, it's a matter of preference - I tend to be somewhat prejudiced against inheritance as a solution to most OOP problems.  In this case, in my opinion only, I find that using a Facade lets me concentrate on my domain problems, i.e. writing specific types of Excel content.  Rather than having to worry about XlsWriter's class internals, which you do have to track if you use inheritance.  As always, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

`write_results` is a method of *worksheet*, so you'll have to create a class inherited from `Worksheet` too. There you'll be able to write your `write_results`. *And* you'll have to reimplement the method where the *worksheet* is created. Looking into code it's [_add_sheet](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/blob/master/xlsxwriter/workbook.py#L606)

Not elegant, I'm affraid, but that is what you're asking.

Comment: I think that this is a solution but it will take a lot of work as this is the first obstacle I'm sure that I'll find many others when I'll use charts, formats etc... I still hope there is another solution instead of create other classes and override existing methods just to add new methods, maybe I'll have to face the harsh truth that there isn't another way